# Calculating pivoting load

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I’m trying to determine the breaking strength that would be needed for a rope that will pull up a 250# bronze centerboard on a sailboat.

I hope the drawing illustrates the necessary dimensions and pivot points. The green line is the rope.

An estimate is more than sufficient.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Take moments about the pivot point

$250*e  - T*sin\theta *a - T*cos\theta *b = 0$

$T = \dfrac{250*e}{sin\theta *a + cos\theta *b}$

$T$ is the minimum expected tension in the rope required to lift weight (250 lbs).

Answer (score 0):

The maths is a bit complicated by the changing angle of the green line from the centreboard to the pulley. To solve it properly you would need to work out the general equation for tension and then find the maximum by differentiation.

Just eyeballing the setup the worst case appears to me to be when the board is fully up. The centre of gravity would be about 36"/2 - 1 = 17" back from the pivot and the line pulling on a radius of about 20" - 1 = 19" so it has slight mechanical advantage. With the mechanical advantage the tension would be < 250 lb. (OK, $250 \times 17 = 4250\ \mathrm{in\cdot lb}$ so the tension in the line would be $ \frac {4250}{19} = 223\ \mathrm{lb}$.)

If I had to do it a bit more rigorously I would,

- Figure out the centre of gravity of the centreboard. Most 3D CAD programs will do that for you. [OnShape](https://onshape.com) works in your browser and is free to use if you don't mind your designs being public.
- Draw out the situation for 0°, 30°, 60° and 90° and calculate the turning moment. I think the line tension would then be scaled up by $\frac 1 {cos\ \alpha}$ where $\alpha$ is the angle of the green line from the horizontal. (i.e. The tension required is minimum when the line is horizontal.)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was expecting that the load on the rope would be greater than the weight of the board since there’s more of the board below the pivot point than above, so I’m glad I asked. I’m planning to use rope that has a breaking strength of 8,500 pounds, so I should be safe!

Answer (score 0):

the maximum tension is when the board is fully lifted. and the rope is horizontal.

$$\Sigma M_{pivot}=0$$

$$T=250*(36/2")/20=225lbs$$

using a safety factor of two,

$$T=225*2=450lbd$$